# Cifra de vigenere

Tags: c#, .net, array, algoritmo, criptografia

```
 private static void algoritmo(String input, String chave, Boolean b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Digite a mensagem: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Digite a chave: ");
        chave = Console.ReadLine();
        input = input.ToUpper();
        chave = chave.ToUpper();


        if (b)
        {
            // para cada caracter da entrada, com exceção do espaço, converterá para valor ascii
            for (int contaCar = 0; contaCar < input.Length; contaCar++)
            {
                if (input.Equals(" "))
                {
                    output += input;
                }
                else
                {
                    char carTex = (char)input[contaCar];
                    output += carTex;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            // para cada caracter da chave, com exceção do espaço, converterá para valor ascii
            for (int contaCar = 0; contaCar < chave.Length; contaCar++)
            {
                if (chave.Equals(" "))
                {
                    codeKey += chave;
                }
                else
                {
                    char asciiChave = (char)chave[contaCar];
                    codeKey += asciiChave;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(codeKey);
            // agora que a mensagem está transformada em ascii(output) assim como a chave (codeKey),
            // deverá ocorrer a codificação
            for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < codeKey.Length; j++)
                {
                    code = ((codeKey[j] + output[i]) - 65) % 26;
                }
            }
            Console.Write(code);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

O objetivo seria fazer com que cada caractere da chave recebesse seu valor ASCII e retornasse como um *array* pra eu poder fazer algumas operações de soma entre cada valor ASCII de cada caractere. Por exemplo: valores ASCII da palavra `"nome": [65, 67, ...]` e valores ASCII da chave `"cade": [65, 67, ...]`, assim eu somaria os valores de mesmo índice de *array*.

Como eu posso fazer para o `output` e do `codeKey` sair com os valores ASCII da entrada?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Demorou pra eu entender o que o código deveria fazer. Agora gostei da brincadeira  e fiz o que deveria ter sido feito.

Separei a parte de interface do algoritmo, dei nomes melhores para tudo.

Eu falei na pergunta anterior que para o algoritmo não precisava do `ToUpper()`, usei só na interface por conveniência.

Idealmente deveria ter um método para cifrar e outro para decifrar. Isso eu não arrumei. Tem como aproveitar esse código para decifrar, só muda a fórmula.

Só um laço basta. Na verdade um aninhado no outro não produziria o resultado esperado.

Já filtrei os caracteres que são aceitos e promovi para maiúsculo dentro do laço para ganhar velocidade.

Pesquisei qual era a fórmula correta e apliquei. Não garanto que está feito da melhor maneira, mas isso também é uma pseudo-criptografia.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        int escolha = 1;
        while (escolha != 0) {
            WriteLine("ESCOLHA UMA OPÇÃO");
            WriteLine("-----------------");
            WriteLine("1-Encriptar");
            WriteLine("2-Decriptar");
            WriteLine("0-Encerrar");
            WriteLine("-----------------");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out escolha) || escolha < 0 || escolha > 2) {
                WriteLine("Opção inválida");
                continue;
            }
            if (escolha != 0) {
                WriteLine("Digite a mensagem: ");
                var mensagem = ReadLine();
                WriteLine("Digite a chave: ");
                var chave = ReadLine();
                WriteLine(mensagem.ToUpper());
                WriteLine(chave.ToUpper());
                WriteLine(CifraVigenere(mensagem, chave, escolha == 1));
            }
        }
    }
    private static string CifraVigenere(string mensagem, string chave, bool flag) {
        if (flag) {
            var codigo = "";
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < mensagem.Length; i++, j++) {
                char c = char.ToUpper(mensagem[i]);
                if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') continue;
                codigo += (char)((c + char.ToUpper(chave[j % chave.Length]) - 2 * 'A') % 26 + 'A');
            }
            return codigo;
        }
        return ""; //até criar o decript
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Hw1gg6). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WoA922). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/CifraVigenere.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Cabeçalhos private void Decifra(string cifra, string chave)

```
 private void Decifra(string cifra, string chave){
            var mensagem = "";
            for (int i = 0 ; i < cifra.Length; i++)
            {
                char c = char.ToUpper(cifra[i]);
                if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z')
                {
                    continue;
                }
            char cha = char.ToUpper(chave[i % chave.Length]);
                mensagem += (char)((26-(cha%65-c%65))%26+65);
            }
        c.Text = mensagem;

    }
```

Comment: Esta resposta foi sinalizada como de baixa qualidade devido ao tamanho ou conteúdo. Por favor, se possível e se esta for uma solução ao problema, explique melhor como você o resolveu. O código pode ser trivial para você, mas para outros usuários pode não ser.

Comment: é apenas um método de decifrar complementando o programa acima

Comment: e o resultado é enviado pra uma textbox

Comment: Você pode [edit] a resposta e adicionar essas informações direto nela.

Comment: foi mal, sou novo aqui.

Comment: Começando a programar agora